# Convert column and sub column into row

Tags: python, pandas, melt

I have below data in an Excel file with column marks & sub column $

```
        |   Marks   |
______________________
Student | $ |%  |#  |
______________________
Joy     | 7 |2  |0  |
RED     | 9 |2  |5  |
CTL     | 5 |0  |4  |
```

I want to convert column into row in below format:

```
Student | Marks | Symbol |
--------|-------|--------|
Joy     | 7     |    $   |
Joy     | 2     |    %   |
Joy     | 0     |    #   |   
RED     | 9     |    $   | 
RED     | 2     |    %   |
RED     | 5     |    #   | 
CTL     | 5     |    $   |
CTL     | 0     |    %   | 
CTL     | 4     |    #   |
```

For converting into row I am using this code for conversion. I want the above output after converting from column to row but getting some random value. What needs to be done to get the above output?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
tdf = df.reset_index( col_level = 1 )
tdf

dfs = pd.melt( tdf, id_vars = ['Student'], value_vars = [ '$', '%', '#' ], col_level = 1, var_name = 'Symbol' )
dfs = dfs.rename( columns = { 'value': 'Marks' } )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What do you mean, "melt is not correct"? Can you post the full traceback you get?

Comment: My guess is the issue is that you have a `MultiIndex` and aren't specifying the full value of the index in the `melt` method.

Comment: Another issue could be if the `Student` column is the DataFrame's index, you can't use it as an element in `id_vars` in `melt`.

Comment: @gimix I want mentioned output after converting from coloumn to row but getting some random value. can you help me with this or instant of  melt what else we can use

Comment: @bicarlsen i am not sure in melt function as its not working for me, can you help me with this or instant of melt what else we can use

Comment: @TeenaAgrawal also add the output you are getting and share df.columns output.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is move `Student` into the DataFrame if it is the index.

```py
tdf = df.reset_index( col_level = 1 )
```

Then you can perform the `pd.melt`.

```py
dfs = pd.melt( tdf, id_vars = [ 'Student' ], value_vars = [ '$', '%', '#' ], col_level = 1, var_name = 'Symbol' )
dfs = dfs.rename( columns = { 'value': 'Marks' } )
```

Comment: Thanks but after applying this code i am getting again error: 
"The following 'id_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['Student']"

Comment: The error seems quite descriptive. Ensure that the `Student` data is a column of the DataFrame and not the index, and that everything is spelled correctly. If you still can't get it working correclty your can pickle the DataFrame and post a link to it in your question so we can look at it directly.

Comment: This is my full code which i am using :
'
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
tdf = df.reset_index( col_level = 1 )
tdf

dfs = pd.melt( tdf, id_vars = ['Student'], value_vars = [ '$', '%', '#' ], col_level = 1, var_name = 'Symbol' )
dfs = dfs.rename( columns = { 'value': 'Marks' } )'

addedd code in question also

Comment: i have added my complete code in question too

Comment: Without having access to your DataFrame I wonlt be able to debug any further. Again, I would suggest checking the format fo the DataFrame.

Comment: I have added my complete code so now you can create same at your end too

Comment: Yes, that is not the issue. The issue is that you need to provide access to the `test.xlsx` file, or the DataFrame that you are trying to manipulate (e.g. using `pickle`).

Comment: test file is same as I provided in question. I named it as test.xlsx file.

Comment: If it's the same then the code should work. I've tested it duplicating your exact DataFrame structure using `Student` as an index for the original DataFrame and having a column MultiIndex of  tyoe ( `Mark`, `symbol` ). This is why I was asking for the actual data file you are testing it with.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Sample df
symbols = np.array(['$', '%', '#'])
data = [
    ['Joy', 7,2,0],
    ['Red', 9,2,5],
    ['CTL', 5,0,4]
]

id_vars = [('', 'Student')]
value_vars = [('Marks', i) for i in symbols]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(id_vars + value_vars)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)

# df:
#|           Marks      
#|   Student     $  %  #
#| 0     Joy     7  2  0
#| 1     Red     9  2  5
#| 2     CTL     5  0  4
```

```py
tdf = df.reset_index()
dfs = pd.melt( tdf, id_vars = [ 'Student' ], value_vars = [ '$', '%', '#' ], col_level = 1, var_name = 'Symbol' )
dfs = dfs.rename( columns = { 'value': 'Marks' } )

# dfs:
#|   Student Symbol  Marks
#| 0     Joy      $      7
#| 1     Red      $      9
#| 2     CTL      $      5
#| 3     Joy      %      2
#| 4     Red      %      2
#| 5     CTL      %      0
#| 6     Joy      #      0
#| 7     Red      #      5
#| 8     CTL      #      4
```

```py
ntdata = np.hstack((df.T.values[1:], np.array_split(symbols, len(symbols))))
ndf = pd.DataFrame(ntdata)

ncolumns = df[('', 'Student')].values.tolist()
ndf.columns = ncolumns + ['Symbol']
ndf = ndf.melt(id_vars = [ 'Symbol' ], value_vars = ncolumns, var_name = 'Student' )
ndf = ndf.rename( columns = { 'value': 'Marks' } )

# ndf:
#|   Symbol Student  Marks
#| 0      $     Joy      7
#| 1      %     Joy      2
#| 2      #     Joy      0
#| 3      $     Red      9
#| 4      %     Red      2
#| 5      #     Red      5
#| 6      $     CTL      5
#| 7      %     CTL      0
#| 8      #     CTL      4
```

Here working [example](https://paiza.io/projects/SxgjTcMfbeerCIwk-swNQw)